# MYSQL error regarding syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'exit, openclosed, longshort, target_one, target_two,
>   target_three, notes, entryd' at line 1

For this php script that I'm trying to run from MYSQL.

```
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stockpicks (symbol, entry, exit, openclosed, longshort, target_one, target_two, target_three, notes, entrydate) 
        VALUES('$symbol','$entry','$exit','$openclosed','$longshort','$target_one','$target_two','$target_three','$notes',now())") or die (mysql_error());
```

The problem is I see no error. I've checked both this particular line and the lines surrounding. For example I re did the '$var' section which has given me trouble in the past, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. My table structure is as follows

id int(11)

symbol varchar(255)

entry   varchar(255)

exit    varchar(255)

openclosed  varchar(255)

entrydate   datetime

longshort   varchar(255)

target_one  varchar(255)

target_two  varchar(255)

target_three    varchar(255)

Comment: There's really no need for all that code, we only need to see the query here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). If you want to use it as a column name, quote it in backticks:

```
`exit`
```

Comment: Reminds me of the `Release` reserved word in MySQL which drove me to drink when I started using MySQL 5... .

Comment: Really something I never knew. I've just never used it before as a column name. You learn something new everyday. Namphibian it has been driving me crazy, thats for sure. Thanks deceze, that cleared things up for me and it worked great. Is it advised that we not use exit or just backtick it when necessary?

Comment: @Hire As the linked-to manual says: *"Certain words such as SELECT, DELETE, or BIGINT are reserved and require special treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names. [...] Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them..."* - As long as you quote them, they're fine to use.

Comment: Thanks deceze. I'm sorry my original post was reviewed poorly, but I hope others can gain some value from this post. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO stockpicks (symbol, entry, `exit`, openclosed, longshort, target_one, target_two, target_three, notes, entrydate) 
        VALUES('$symbol','$entry','$exit','$openclosed','$longshort','$target_one','$target_two','$target_three','$notes',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
```

Note that escaping your identifiers in MySQL way using backticks decreases portability on a plain place.

I would either use double quotes with ANSI SQL mode enabled, or just give my variables names which are unlikely to be become reserved in future.

`exit` is a reserved word in mysql.